# Making a div on top of everything with z-index doesn't work?

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, google-maps, z-index

I'm using wordpress plugin *Basic Google Maps Placemarks* to display the map, but I have to put it in a very slim spot (width=300px) . Now I want to hack that plugin, hoping that the overflow of pop out window will be visible. To start, I'm testing with Google Chrome's inspect element tool. But no matter how I change the z-index of that div, it's always hidden.

Screenshot below:

[image]

This is the website I'm working on : http://starrystory.org/

Did I miss something? How could I make that div on top of everything else?

P.S. 
If it can't be done with just CSS, does anyone have jQuery solution maybe?

Answer (score 2):

As the parent elements have `overflow: hidden` and the dimensions of the canvas, no inner element will show outside of their boundaries.

You'd have to move the popup element outside of the overflow hidden containers. Which in this case would be tricky.

Comment: @Arch1tect, yes, but that will break other things. The map needs to be contained.

Comment: Right....now I'm thinking about using jQuery to get the div then make a new popup div with the same content at the same position but on top of everything, and it should keep track of the original popup all the time..seems very troublesome..